# R.java in Drawable Syntax error on token "int", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The code where the error is:

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static int =0x7f020145;
    public static int ab_background=0x7f020000;
    public static int ab_bottom_solid_termoweb=0x7f020001;
}
```

I tried to make a clean, build, modify R directly, even erase R to generate it again. but it reappears.

I'm using Eclipse

EDIT. Just solve the problem, drawables had a file with an "ï", which makes failure R, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve the problem, drawables had a file with an "ï", which makes failure R.